# haml accepts my canvas but does not like my z index style attribute

Tags: html, canvas, haml

anyone experienced in haml and knows how to use it with canvas ?

```
%canvas#myCanvas{:width => 1000, :height => 1000, :style => z-index: 2}
```

haml does not like my z-index i get an error when i want to haml

```
Syntax error on line 131: input.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
...ght => 1000, :style => z-index: 2)}></canvas>\n    <canvas i...
...                               ^
input.haml:8: unknown regexp options - cava
input.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
...vas id='layerCanvas'></canvas>\n  </body>\n</html>\n", -2, f...
...                               ^
input.haml:8: unknown regexp options - htl
input.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
...></canvas>\n  </body>\n</html>\n", -2, false);;_erbout
...                               ^
input.haml:8: unterminated string meets end of file
input.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting tSTRING_DEND
...</html>\n", -2, false);;_erbout
...                               ^
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Answer (score 1):

The attributes need to be valid Ruby. In particular, this is invalid:

```
:style => z-index: 2
```

You need to quote the value:

```
:style => "z-index: 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

well this issue is solved by using a converter from html2haml.